# Add Classes to Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to add class names to a React Component to make it easier for me to customize that component using Styled Components. Here is a simplified outline of the component:

```
const SignupForm = props => (
    <form>
      <Input className="input" />
      <Button className="button" />
    </form>
  )
```

And here is how I would like to use it:

```
import { SignupForm } from '../path/to/signup-form'

  <Form />
...

const Form = styled(SignupForm)`
  .input {
     /* Custom Styles */
  }

  .button {
     /* Custom Styles */
  }
`
```

However, this does not work. Only if I create a wrapper Component will it work - like this:

```
import { SignupForm } from '../path/to/signup-form'

  <FormWrapper>
    <SignupForm/>
  <FormWrapper>
...

const FormWrapper = styled.div`
  .input {
     /* Custom Styles */
  }

  .button {
     /* Custom Styles */
  }
`
```

I'm wondering whether or not there is a way to access the `.input` and `.button` classes **without** having to create a wrapper class, i.e. via the actual imported class itself? If so, how?

Comment: `ref` from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)  may help you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to provide `className` for the wrapper/container as `styled-component` injecting the styles through it:

```
const SignupForm = ({ className }) => (
  <form className={className}>
    <input className="input" />
    <button className="button">Button</button>
  </form>
);

const Form = styled(SignupForm)`
  .input {
    background-color: palegreen;
  }

  .button {
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit hungry-moser-3lu0p]

Answer (score 24):

Just add extra atrribute `className` by using `attrs` to existing styled component.

```
const FormWrapper = styled.div.attrs({
  className: 'SignupForm',
  })`
    .input {
    /* Custom Styles */
    }

   .button {
   /* Custom Styles */
   }
   `
```