# styled(MyComponent) renders MyComponent but without additional styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have 2 React's component that are using styled-component. First one called `Div` render just a simple `div` (just for the example):

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Div(props) {
  return <StyledDiv>{props.children}</StyledDiv>;
}

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  border: 10px solid red;
`;
```

It render correctly a `div` with a red border.

Then I tried to render this component in another one (called `App`) using styled-components `styled()` function:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import Div from "./Div";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledApp>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </StyledApp>
  );
}

const StyledApp = styled(Div)`
  color: red;
`;
```

Result here is a `div` with a red border containing my `h1` and `h2` but the `color: red` is not taking into account. My titles stays black.

Here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-water-yjywh?file=/src/App.js).

Have I missed something from the `styled()` function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `className` prop.

See [styling normal React components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).

> If you use the `styled(MyComponent)` notation and `MyComponent` does not render the passed-in `className` prop, **then no styles will be applied**.

```
export default function Div({ className, children }) {
  return <StyledDiv className={className}>{children}</StyledDiv>;
}
```

[image: Edit naughty-snowflake-t8bil]

Comment: You yourself have answered this question before, should have marked it as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756648/add-classes-to-styled-component/59756799#59756799

Comment: Yes, you are right, sometimes I just prefer to answer faster than doing this procedure, sorry.

Comment: yes but by doing so you are defeating the purpose of it. I understand there are times when although the solution is same but the way to solve it is different, in such cases its okay to answer, but here its the exact same code