# Styled Components with more readable class names

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I created few components using styled components and their output generates a hashed class name that makes debugging harder.

```
const StyledMessageBlock = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 200;
  height: 25px;
`;
```

[image]

So, I tried to import styled from macros `import styled from 'styled-components/macro';` and the outcome still the same.

I tried then updating the `.babelrc` file with some configurations but it didn't work as well.

```
"plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-macros"],
    [
        "babel-plugin-styled-components",
        {
            "minify": true,
            "transpileTemplateLiterals": false,
            "pure": true,
            "displayName": true, // generate another classname
            "fileName": true, // generate another classname
            "preprocess": false,
            "meaninglessFileNames": ["index", "styles"]
        }
    ]
]
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. The expected outcome would be a class name something like `sc_StyledMessageBlock_bdvvtL`.

Comment: I assume you've already tried adding the classnames to the actual components (in this case the <div /> component)? 

something like this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756648/add-classes-to-styled-component

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `styled-components v4+`, you can use their [babel macro plugin](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro), which will prepend the unreadable class with `styled__<ComponentName>`.