# convert to styled component from css (ternary operator)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Im trying to convert my project from css to styled component(https://styled-components.com/), at the moment i have converted all my other components except one component i have stuck, checked others examples from stackoverflow but it was not same kind.
I have conditional class names

My question is how to convert InfoBox component to use styled component, my problem is this 'className' which is a little complicated to convert to styled component, any ideas ?

english is not my mother language so could be mistaked

my code:

```html
import React from 'react'
import "./InfoBox.css"
import { Card } from "@material-ui/core"

function InfoBox({ isRed, active, activetored, ...props }) {
    return (
        <Card onClick={props.onClick}
            className={`infoBox ${active && "infoBox--selected"} 
            ${activetored && "infoBox--selectedtored"}
            ${isRed && "infoBox--red"} `} >
           
        </Card>
    )
}

export default InfoBox
```

```html
<div className="app__stats">
          <InfoBox
            isRed
            active={typeofCase === "cases"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('cases')}
           
          />
          <InfoBox
            isGreen
            active={typeofCase === "recovered"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('recovered')}
         
          />
          <InfoBox
            isRed
            activetored={typeofCase === "deaths"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('deaths')}
           
          />
        </div>
```

css is like this (you can put whatever):

```css
 . infoBox--selected {
  border-top: 10px solid greenyellow;
  }

  . infoBox--selectedtored {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  }

  . infoBox--red {
  border-color: darkblue;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Classes to Styled Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756648/add-classes-to-styled-component)

Comment: @AlexGru no its different, mine has conditional class names

Answer (score 2):

To start, please see [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) how to use props with styled-components.
With those props you can do anything you want inside a styled component and you can achieve this in your code like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./InfoBox.css"
import { Card } from "@material-ui/core"
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
  border-top: ${({$active, $activetored}) => $active ? '10px solid greenyellow' : $activetored && '10px solid red'};
  border-color: ${({$isRed}) => $isRed && 'darkblue'};
`

function InfoBox({ isRed, active, activetored, ...props }) {
    return (
        <StyledCard $isRed={isRed} $active={active} $activetored={activetored} onClick={props.onClick}>
           
        </StyledCard>
    )
}

export default InfoBox
```

Please notice that **active** and **activetored** may override each other depends on your order of ternary condition if both are true. Your example does not show such a case were both props are set to true so it should be okay.

Comment: @walee was that what you were looking for?

Comment: this is not working, those props coming from InfoBox to StyledCard has no any affect

Comment: onClick does not work either, do we need '    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
' ?

Comment: I am not sure this is necessary. Do you have a reproducible link to codesandbox or similar so I can try to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since it wasn't clear at first, here's a solution if you're using [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) instead:

First, import the actual styles from your CSS file:

```js
import * as styles from "./InfoBox.css"
```

Then you can refer to the available classes in `className`, like this:

```js
className={styles['infoBox'] + `${active && styles['infoBox--selected']`}
```

Comment: no i mean this one : const Div = styled.div`
 `, but you can keep that one also it helps others

Comment: i want to get rid of css and use styled-components instead

Answer (score 0):

For conditional class names I suggest using classnames import:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

The syntax is really easy to read and you can create however complex classnames with it. In your case the code could be something like this:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

....

className={classNames('infoBox', {
  'infoBox--selected': active,
  'infoBox--selectedtored': activetored,
  'infoBox--red': isRed
})}
```

Comment: i want to use this styled-components.com