# conditional className convert to styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Im trying to learn and convert my project from css to styled component(https://styled-components.com/), at the moment i have converted all my other components except one component where i am stuck, checked others examples from stackoverflow but it was not same kind.
I have conditional class names

My question is how to convert InfoBox component to use styled component ? do i need to  inject the styles through some kind of styled-component wrapper or thats not needed ?

english is not my mother language so could be mistaked

my code:

```html
import React from 'react'
import "./InfoBox.css"

function InfoBox({ isRed, active, activetored, ...props }) {
    return (
        <div onClick={props.onClick}
            className={`infoBox ${active && "infoBox--selected"} 
            ${activetored && "infoBox--selectedtored"}
            ${isRed && "infoBox--red"} `} >
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default InfoBox
```

```html
<div className="app__stats">
          <InfoBox
            isRed
            active={typeofCase === "cases"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('cases')}
           
          />
          <InfoBox
            isGreen
            active={typeofCase === "recovered"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('recovered')}
         
          />
          <InfoBox
            isRed
            activetored={typeofCase === "deaths"}
            onClick={(e) => setTypeofCase('deaths')}
           
          />
        </div>
```

css is like this (you can put whatever):

```css
 . infoBox--selected {
  border-top: 10px solid greenyellow;
  }

  . infoBox--selectedtored {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  }

  . infoBox--red {
  border-color: darkblue;
  }
```

Comment: thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert to styled component from css (ternary operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864334/convert-to-styled-component-from-css-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas behind styled-component is to avoid classnames.
Instead of setting the css by class, you have few options. the easiest one will probably be to use your props inside the css code, and change the style by it:

```html
const InfoBox = styeld.div`
  border-color: ${props => props.isRed ? 'darkblue' : 'black'};
  border-top: ${props => props.active ? '10px solid greenyellow' : 'red'};
  ...
`;
```

this way, you don't need classnames (although it can be done with it too, obviously).

Now, instead of the div inside the component, use the InfoBox styled component we just wrote and you good to go.

Comment: what if that is not a div inside the component but '<Card>' from @material-ui/core instead ? like this <Card  className={`infoBox ${activetored && "infoBox--selectedtored"} ${isRed && "infoBox--red"} `} ></Card>

Comment: not sure if its support styled-components, but if so, you just define it as a styled conponent like this: ```const InfoBox = styled(Card)` ...css...`;```

Comment: if you don't wanna mess around, you can just wrap the <Card> with some container, pass the classes, and do this: ```const Container = styled.div` .is-red { color: red; } .selected { color: green }  `;``` and so on..