# Styled Components with React, driving colours using state

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using a clicked state for 3 components, when each component is clicked, it will set the state to e.g 1,2,3.

This is pretty basic but it looks like this.

```
    const [selectedTemplate, setSelectedTemplate] = useState(0)

            <TemplateContainer>
                <DummyTemplateImage
                onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedTemplate(1);
                    }}
                >
                    <ImageContainer src={General}/>
                </DummyTemplateImage>
                <Typography variant="h5" fontSize="18px" color="primary">
                    Text!!
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle4" color="black">
                Text!
                </Typography>
            </TemplateContainer>
```

Pretty simple. However, when the box is selected, e.g you select option 1, i'd like it to change the  background to be green.

This is my styled-component.

```
const TemplateContainer = styled.div`
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;

`;
```

How would I drive this?

Comment: Your `TemplateContainer` needs to take parameters so you can pass `selectedTemplate` into it

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756648/add-classes-to-styled-component